# Spring Boot, Docker, Bash - automated test url issue

Tags: spring, bash, docker, automated-tests

At first, all my current unit and integration tests are passing however I am struggling with .bash script of automated test. They are reather simple, just post data into docker contrainer database and the assert curls however I am struggling with posting one of Entity. Exception looks like:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-12-18T16:01:42.980+0000","path":"/movie-composite","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"I/O error on POST request for \"http://review:8080/review\": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"}{"timestamp":"2019-12-18T16:01:43.073+0000","path":"/movie-composite","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"I/O error on POST request for \"http://review:8080/review\": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"}Test OK (HTTP Code: 200)
Test OK (actual value: 1)
Test OK (actual value: 3)
Test FAILED, EXPECTED VALUE: 1, ACTUAL VALUE: 0, WILL ABORT
```

Which means that from this assertion

```
# Verify that a normal request works, expect three recommendations and on review
assertCurl 200 "curl http://$HOST:$PORT/movie-composite/1 -s"
assertEqual 1 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq .movieId)
assertEqual 3 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".recommendations | length")
assertEqual 1 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".reviews | length")
```

Last one so:

```
assertEqual 1 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".reviews | length")
```

fails.

I think that this is related to this part of stacktrace:

```
 error on POST request for \"http://review:8080/review\": Connection refused
```

however this are my first hours with contenerization so I am only guessing.. :)

So I will start first with my application structure. There are 3 microservices for Entites like Movie, Review, Recommendation and all of them are posted by MovieComposite which is just aggregate of these three entities and it looks like:

```
{
    "genre": "Science Fiction",
    "movieId": 113,
    "title": "Star Wars 1",
    "reviews": [
      {
        "reviewId": 1,
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "content": "Fake Review content of Jane Doe",
        "subject": "Review of Jane Doe"
      },
      {
        "reviewId": 1,
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "content": "Fake Review content of Jane Doe",
        "subject": "Review of Jane Doe"
      },
      {
        "reviewId": 2,
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "content": "Fake Review content of Jane Doe",
        "subject": "Review of Jane Doe"
      }
    ]
  }
```

With that composite service is making calls to other microservices.
When testing it manually via curl, postman or by unit and integration testing everygthing is fine, however I am strugglig with containerization.

When I run docker-compose up and then make POST request via POSTMAN everything is fine. There is something wrong with my .bash script however I cannot find what I am missing.

Docker compose looks like:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  movie:
    build: microservices/movie-service
    mem_limit: 350m
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  recommendation:
    build: microservices/recommendation-service
    mem_limit: 350m
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  review:
    build: microservices/review-service
    mem_limit: 350m
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

  movie-composite:
    build: microservices/movie-composite-service
    mem_limit: 350m
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker

  # $ mongo
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6.9
    mem_limit: 350m
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --smallfiles

  # $ mysql -uroot -h127.0.0.1 -p
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    mem_limit: 350m
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpwd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=review-db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-uuser", "-ppwd", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
  retries: 10
```

and .bash script for automated test which fails:
What is more this is only responsible for doing steps in order:
 **mvn clean install -> docker-compose up -> assert curls -> docker-compose down**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Sample usage:
#
#   HOST=localhost PORT=7000 ./test-em-all.bash
#
: ${HOST=localhost}
: ${PORT=8080}

function assertCurl() {

  local expectedHttpCode=$1
  local curlCmd="$2 -w \"%{http_code}\""
  local result=$(eval $curlCmd)
  local httpCode="${result:(-3)}"
  RESPONSE='' && ((${#result} > 3)) && RESPONSE="${result%???}"

  if [ "$httpCode" = "$expectedHttpCode" ]; then
    if [ "$httpCode" = "200" ]; then
      echo "Test OK (HTTP Code: $httpCode)"
    else
      echo "Test OK (HTTP Code: $httpCode, $RESPONSE)"
    fi
  else
    echo "Test FAILED, EXPECTED HTTP Code: $expectedHttpCode, GOT: $httpCode, WILL ABORT!"
    echo "- Failing command: $curlCmd"
    echo "- Response Body: $RESPONSE"
    exit 1
  fi
}

function assertEqual() {

  local expected=$1
  local actual=$2

  if [ "$actual" = "$expected" ]; then
    echo "Test OK (actual value: $actual)"
  else
    echo "Test FAILED, EXPECTED VALUE: $expected, ACTUAL VALUE: $actual, WILL ABORT"
    exit 1
  fi
}

function testUrl() {
  url=$@
  if curl $url -ks -f -o /dev/null; then
    echo "Ok"
    return 0
  else
    echo -n "not yet"
    return 1
  fi
}

function waitForService() {
  url=$@
  echo -n "Wait for: $url... "
  n=0
  until testUrl $url; do
    n=$((n + 1))
    if [[ $n == 100 ]]; then
      echo " Give up"
      exit 1
    else
      sleep 6
      echo -n ", retry #$n "
    fi
  done
}

function recreateComposite() {
  local movieId=$1
  local composite=$2

  curl -X POST http://$HOST:$PORT/movie-composite -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "$composite"
}

function setupData() {

  body='{
    "genre": "Science Fiction",
    "movieId": 1,
    "title": "Star Wars 1",
    "recommendations": [
      {
        "author": "John Doe",
        "content": "Fake content of John Doe",
        "rate": 5,
        "recommendationId": 1
      },
      {
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "content": "Fake content of Jane Doe",
        "rate": 4,
        "recommendationId": 2
      },
      {
        "author": "Mike Fake",
        "content": "Fake content of Mike Fake",
        "rate": 2,
        "recommendationId": 3
      }
    ],
    "reviews": [
      {
        "reviewId": 1,
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "content": "Fake Review content of Jane Doe",
        "subject": "Review of Jane Doe"
      }
    ]
  }'
  recreateComposite 1 "$body"

  body='{
    "genre": "Science Fiction",
    "movieId": 113,
    "title": "Star Wars 1",
    "reviews": [
      {
        "reviewId": 1,
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "content": "Fake Review content of Jane Doe",
        "subject": "Review of Jane Doe"
      },
      {
        "reviewId": 1,
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "content": "Fake Review content of Jane Doe",
        "subject": "Review of Jane Doe"
      },
      {
        "reviewId": 2,
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "content": "Fake Review content of Jane Doe",
        "subject": "Review of Jane Doe"
      }
    ]
  }'
  recreateComposite 113 "$body"

  body='{
    "genre": "Science Fiction",
    "movieId": 213,
    "title": "Star Wars 1",
    "recommendations": [
      {
        "author": "John Doe",
        "content": "Fake content of John Doe",
        "rate": 5,
        "recommendationId": 4
      },
      {
        "author": "Jane Doe",
        "content": "Fake content of Jane Doe",
        "rate": 4,
        "recommendationId": 5
      },
      {
        "author": "Mike Fake",
        "content": "Fake content of Mike Fake",
        "rate": 2,
        "recommendationId": 6
      }
    ]
  }'
  recreateComposite 213 "$body"
}

set -e

echo "Start:" $(date)

echo "HOST=${HOST}"
echo "PORT=${PORT}"

if [[ $@ == *"start"* ]]; then
  echo "Restarting the test environment..."
  echo "$ docker-compose down"
  docker-compose down

  echo "$ mvn clean install"
  mvn clean install

  echo "$ docker-compose up -d"
  docker-compose up -d
fi

setupData

# Verify that a normal request works, expect three recommendations and on review
assertCurl 200 "curl http://$HOST:$PORT/movie-composite/1 -s"
assertEqual 1 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq .movieId)
assertEqual 3 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".recommendations | length")
assertEqual 1 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".reviews | length")

# Verify that a 404 (Not Found) error is returned for a non existing movieId (13)
assertCurl 404 "curl http://$HOST:$PORT/movie-composite/13 -s"

# Verify that no recommendations are returned for movieId 113
assertCurl 200 "curl http://$HOST:$PORT/movie-composite/113 -s"
assertEqual 113 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq .movieId)
assertEqual 0 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".recommendations | length")
assertEqual 3 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".reviews | length")

# Verify that no reviews are returned for movieId 213
assertCurl 200 "curl http://$HOST:$PORT/movie-composite/213 -s"
assertEqual 213 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq .movieId)
assertEqual 3 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".recommendations | length")
assertEqual 0 $(echo $RESPONSE | jq ".reviews | length")

# Verify that a 422 (Unprocessable Entity) error is returned for a movieId that is out of range (-1)
assertCurl 422 "curl http://$HOST:$PORT/movie-composite/-1 -s"
assertEqual "\"Invalid movieId: -1\"" "$(echo $RESPONSE | jq .message)"

# Verify that a 400 (Bad Request) error error is returned for a movieId that is not a number, i.e. invalid format
assertCurl 400 "curl http://$HOST:$PORT/movie-composite/invalidProductId -s"
assertEqual "\"Type mismatch.\"" "$(echo $RESPONSE | jq .message)"

if [[ $@ == *"stop"* ]]; then
  echo "We are done, stopping the test environment..."
  echo "$ docker-compose down"
  docker-compose down
fi

echo "End:" $(date)
```